# How to put the search in another thread without craching the UI?

Tags: swift, multithreading, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a searchbar and a tableview which display the results.
i have a data with 150.000 foods (it's a very big data)
So when the user tap letters, the UI blocks in each letter and take time to search in data and display the results.
The problems isn't about taking time to display the result. The problem is that the keyboard blocks after tapping each letter waiting that the tableview displays the result.
It's not a good user experience.

Here is a part of the code for the searchbar:

```
extension AjoutAlimentController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        let words = Set(searchText.split(separator: " ").map(String.init))
            if searchText.isEmpty {
               baseDeDonneesAlimentsFiltree = [] //baseOuChercheAliments
            } else {
            var baseDeDonneesAlimentsFiltreeClassique = baseOuChercheAliments.filter{$0.nomAliment.range(of: searchText, options: .anchored) != nil}
                baseDeDonneesAlimentsFiltreeClassique.sort(by: { $0.indice > $1.indice})
            var baseDeDonneesAlimentsFiltreeComplexe = baseOuChercheAliments.filter { object in words.allSatisfy { word in object.nomAliment.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(word) } }
                baseDeDonneesAlimentsFiltreeComplexe.sort(by: { $0.indice > $1.indice })
            var soustraction = Array(Set(baseDeDonneesAlimentsFiltreeComplexe).subtracting(baseDeDonneesAlimentsFiltreeClassique))
                soustraction.sort(by: { $0.indice > $1.indice })
            baseDeDonneesAlimentsFiltree = baseDeDonneesAlimentsFiltreeClassique + soustraction
            }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

And here is the code for the tableview:

```
extension AjoutAlimentController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                if baseDeDonneesAlimentsFiltree.count >= 500 {
                    return 500
                } else { return baseDeDonneesAlimentsFiltree.count }
    }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AlimentToAddCell", for: indexPath) as? AlimentToAddCell else {
                    return UITableViewCell() }
                let alimentFind = baseDeDonneesAlimentsFiltree[indexPath.row] // Here is where the crash occures when i put the search in another thread
                cell.indice.text = String(alimentFind.indice.formattedWithSeparator)
                cell.selectionStyle = .none
                return cell
}
```

Is there a way, after the user taps each letter to put the search in a thread without crashing the app? So the UI displays the results with it's rythm and the keyboard doesn't block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always delegate the long time consuming task to global queues (non- ui thread) and once the data is finalized you can always switch to main thread and call `reloadData`

```
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
            let searchTextBeingQuireid = searchText
            var searchedRecords = [AlimentObject]() //not sure type of your array, mention appropriate type here
            let words = Set(searchText.split(separator: " ").map(String.init))
            if searchText.isEmpty {
                searchedRecords = [] //baseOuChercheAliments
            } else {
                var baseDeDonneesAlimentsFiltreeClassique = baseOuChercheAliments.filter{$0.nomAliment.range(of: searchText, options: .anchored) != nil}
                baseDeDonneesAlimentsFiltreeClassique.sort(by: { $0.indice > $1.indice})
                var baseDeDonneesAlimentsFiltreeComplexe = baseOuChercheAliments.filter { object in words.allSatisfy { word in object.nomAliment.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(word) } }
                baseDeDonneesAlimentsFiltreeComplexe.sort(by: { $0.indice > $1.indice })
                var soustraction = Array(Set(baseDeDonneesAlimentsFiltreeComplexe).subtracting(baseDeDonneesAlimentsFiltreeClassique))
                soustraction.sort(by: { $0.indice > $1.indice })
                searchedRecords = baseDeDonneesAlimentsFiltreeClassique + soustraction
            }

            if searchText == searchTextBeingQuireid {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    baseDeDonneesAlimentsFiltree = searchedRecords
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Couple of Optimization you can do:**

Typically, whenever we make a continuous search calls, and data returns asynchronously before we display it on screen, we check the validity of the response itself, assume user types `App` you make a call to search your DB with search text `App` and before data comes back user adds l making text `Appl`, then showing data which has only `App` n not `Appl` will look like a mistake, hence I have added 2 new variables `searchTextBeingQuireid`,`searchedRecords`  once you are done with searching, check if the data you have still valid by checking if `searchTextBeingQuireid` and `searchText` are still same or not. If yes update your data source by calling `baseDeDonneesAlimentsFiltree = searchedRecords` and finally call `reloadData` to update the tableView else ignore the result, next subsequent call will update the result anyway

Comment: i already used your proposition, but it crashes. I mention the crash in the code and it say: Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: the crash occures specially when the user taps letters quickly

Comment: @maria23: Have you used the latest code in answer? Also add complete crash